# asp.net login page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create a login page using asp.net with c#.I have to use sql server 2005 as database..I googled but am not satisfied with the sites i searched.I have to use session for login part..Can some one suggest me good blogs or sites?
I also dont want to use login control from the toolbox.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the standard login control and membership provider?  It already incorporates most best practices, and is very solid.  Before writing your own mechanism, please check out this: http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A3

Comment: Better yet, if you can, consider using OpenID.  See this article for why: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/12/the-dirty-truth-about-web-passwords.html

Comment: Either you use login controls or not is the matter all you need is to write a reasonable code for the requirement you needed. If you tried any post the code so that it will be given in a better way

Answer (score 0):

I would check in to the standard sql server membership provider.  Something like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879kf95c.aspx