# login page in sql server 2005

Tags: c#, asp.net

Am running asp.net applications with c#.I have developed a login page and gave database connection with sql server 2005.Now I want to check the usename and password in my databse.Only if that both matches my page have to redirects to the next page.Can some suggests the code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307420/asp-net-login-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of [**FormAuthentication**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx) with [**Login control**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx) will do your task.